External drive FDE modal window Authentication Required locks interface entirely (Ubuntu 24.04)
From time to time when the disk is detached incorrectly (press unmount but don't wait for a message for safe removal or stuck with some open files) and attaching it again (after sleep) this modal window appears and I can't close it in any way: Alt-Tab, Esc, Cancel, OK just doesn't work. It just blocks the whole interface while everything works fine in the background: YouTube video continues to play and the mouse is responsive.

If I use a Gnome restart method like Alt+F2 then r then a white screen of death shows up. Which is the same as rebooting for me. I remember this problem from Ubuntu 20 I think. Any way to unlock the GUI without rebooting? It's quite frustrating.

